# MySql SELECT using subqueries don't work as expected

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, where-clause

I'm creating a select including several sub-queries but I didn't find a way to use the sub queries values to create the where statement seems to be ignored.
I had 1 content Table, 2 join tables with 2 other tables in join and another table in join wjth the first directly.

I tried several solution, this is latest one

```
select * from (SELECT a.idcontents, a.title, concat(a.filepath, '/', a.filename) as file,
        a.captured_on, a.starred, a.file_type,
        @PL:=(select GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(p.idplaces, '-', p.place) SEPARATOR ', ') from places p where a.idplaces=p.idplaces) as places, 
        @AL:=(select GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(al.idalbum, '-', al.album) SEPARATOR ', ') from album al, join_album_contents am where am.idalbum=al.idalbum and am.idcontents=a.idcontents) as album, 
        @PE:=(select GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(an.idpeople, '-', an.person) SEPARATOR ', ') from people an, join_people_contents ao where ao.idpeople=an.idpeople and ao.idcontents=a.idcontents) as people
        FROM contents a) t
        WHERE (@PE is null OR @AL is null OR @PL=1)
```

but I tried this too

```
SELECT a.idcontents, a.title, concat(a.filepath, '/', a.filename) as file,
        a.captured_on, a.starred, CONCAT(p.idplaces, '-', p.place) as places,
        (select GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(al.idalbum, '-', al.album) SEPARATOR ', ') from album al, join_album_contents am where am.idalbum=al.idalbum and am.idcontents=a.idcontents) as album, 
        (select GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(an.idpeople, '-', an.person) SEPARATOR ', ') from people an, join_people_contents ao where ao.idpeople=an.idpeople and ao.idcontents=a.idcontents) as people
        FROM contents a, places p
        WHERE a.idplaces=p.idplaces
        and (@album IS NULL OR @people IS NULL or p.idplaces=1)
```

Without success, seems the where clause is ignored always and the result contains records with one or all where clauses inside.
Only consolation the records are correctly displayed.

Just to know if there is a solution to resolve this issue.

Solution found in the comments below!!

```
t.people is null or t.album is null or t.places='1'
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Please provide sample data for each of the involved tables, the output you actually get from your query based on that sample, and what you desire to get.

Comment: Why don't you just say (in the first) query `t.people is null or t.album is null or t.place = 1`? You don't need the variables.

Comment: thanks shawnt00!!!! It's works :) I lost two days for this!!! Really thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this equivalent?:

```
SELECT
    a.idcontents, a.title, concat(a.filepath, '/', a.filename) as file,
    a.captured_on, a.starred, a.file_type
FROM contents a
WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (
            select 1
            from people p inner join people_contents pc on pc.idpeople = p.people
            where p.idpeople = a.idcontents /* is this the right column? */
        )
    or  NOT EXISTS (
            select 1
            from album al inner join album_contents ac on ac.idalbum = al.idalbum
            where al.idcontents = a.idcontents
        )
    or  1 = (
            select min(p.idplaces) from places p
            where p.idplaces = a.idplaces
            having count(*) = 1
        )
```